# Preventing StackOverFlow or recursion in Viewmodel property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, properties

I'm stuck in implementing "Keep aspect ratio" feature.
let's say you spin up/down the width control. it directly calculate the height that correspond to w/h ratio vice-versa.
 Since this window has both valueChanged events on code behind. Everytime the value changed, it calls its opposite event.

[image]

I wrote a preventing code for the recursive call.

```
    private void OnChangedPixelWValue(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        if (JustHModified)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (VM.IsKeepAspectRatio)
        {
            double DesiredHeight = VM.ImageSizeX / RatioWH;
            JustHModified = true;
            VM.ImageSizeY = (int)DesiredHeight;
            JustHModified = false;
        }
    }
// ... Same logic exists (OnChangedPixelHValue)
```

every VM properties are bound to UI with Mode Oneway. here is the properties code in ViewModel.

```
    private int m_ImageSizeY;
    public int ImageSizeY
    {
        get { return m_ImageSizeY; }
        set { m_ImageSizeY = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ImageSizeY");
        }
    }
    // ... ImageSizeX exists too
```

Event function code looks so dirty but I'm trying every method to prevent it.
Perhaps I do not fully understand of MVVM logic or missing something.
Call stack like this below

```
1. OnChangedPixelWValue function called
2. ViewModel ImageSizeY property-setter called
3. OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) function called
4. OnChangedPixelHValue function called
...
```

Here are the other questions that I have looked into but it didn't help me.

[Preventing StackOverFlow in recursive functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825530/preventing-stackoverflow-in-recursive-functions)

[How to avoid property recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682999/how-to-avoid-property-recursion)

[How to prevent recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051501/how-to-prevent-recursion)

Comment: IF that checkbox is checked what is the expected behavior? To not modify the image size?

Comment: @RyanWilson it literally keeps the ratio of width and height values. let's say the width/height value preset are 400px,300px. so it's 4:3 ratio. if you spin down width value into 300px. height should be around 225px.

Comment: if (m_ImageSizeY != value) { m_ImageSizeY = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ImageSizeY"); }. The same for X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper solution would require you to implement commands rather than using events.
Event is a pure UI thing and hence should not (in all good cases) be handled on ViewModel

Consider a scenario where you want to plug another control that fires no events, then your code wont work.

Another better way of dealing with situation will be to bind your properties with these controls, and once you change Height, it should update local variable of Width and also call `NotifyProeprtyChange` for both properties and vice versa.

```
public int Width
    {
        get
        {
            return _width;
        }

        set
        {
            _width = value;
            _height = YOUR CALCULATED VALUE
             **All other bits you want to do here**

            OnPropertyChanged("Width");
            OnPropertyChanged("Height");
        }
    }
```

and similar for height property